# How to retreive only the logs I care about from AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, logging, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, logback

**My Issue**

I just deployed my first application to AWS Beanstalk. I have logging in my application using logback. When I download all logs from AWS, I get a huge bundle:

[image]

Not only that, but it is pretty annoying to log in, navigate to my instance, download a big zip file, extract it, navigate to my log, open it, then parse for the info I want.

**The Question**

I really only care about a single one of the log files on AWS - the one I set up my application to create.

What is the easiest way to view only the log file I care about? Best solution would display only the one log file I care about in a web console somewhere, but I don't know if that is possible in AWS. If not, then what is the closest I can get?

Comment: Might want to use AWS Cloudwatch, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the EB console to display logs, or the `eb logs` command-line tool. By default, each will only show the last 100 lines of each log file. You could also script `ssh` or `scp` to just retrieve a single log file.

However, the best solution is probably to publish your application log file to a service like Papertrail or Loggly. If and when you move to a clustered environment, retrieving and searching log files across multiple machines will be a headache unless you're aggregating your logs somehow.